# TX RX test code in CMSIS style simplisity studio

Tags: embedded, uart

Hello I have build bellow the basic stuff of UART initialization .
Now i need to do the operations with sending and receiving DATA registers.

regarding sending the data:

I need to make sure the TXS flag in USARTn_STATUS register is SET,also we use TXDATA register which table shown bellow.

So using CMSIS style writing,but i am not sure regaring two things:

1.how exactly should i define the inverted bitmask that uses to clear the old TXDATA

2.how do i define the binary 5 and in the send register?
Thanks.

```
#include "em_device.h"
#include "em_cmu.h"
#include "em_gpio.h"
#include "em_usart.h"
#include "em_chip.h"

#define BUFFER_SIZE 80
char buffer[BUFFER_SIZE];

/**************************************************************************//**
* @brief  Main function
*****************************************************************************/
int main(void)
{
  USART_InitAsync_TypeDef init = USART_INITASYNC_DEFAULT;
  char welcome_string[] = "Silicon Labs UART Code example!\r\f";
  int i,j;

  // Chip errata
  CHIP_Init();

  // Enable oscillator to GPIO and USART1 modules
  CMU_ClockEnable(cmuClock_GPIO, true);
  CMU_ClockEnable(cmuClock_USART0, true);

  // set pin modes for UART TX and RX pins
  GPIO_PinModeSet(gpioPortC, 1, gpioModeInput, 0);
  GPIO_PinModeSet(gpioPortC, 0, gpioModePushPull, 1);

  // Initialize USART asynchronous mode and route pins
  USART_InitAsync(USART0, &init);
  USART0->ROUTE |= USART_ROUTE_TXPEN | USART_ROUTE_RXPEN;
  if (USART_STATUS_TXC==0) /* Transmition has not started yet */
{
USART0->TXDATA=(USAT0->TXDATA&~_USART_STATUS_TXDATA_MASK)|0b0101) /*send binary 5 from Tx */
USART0->STATUS=(USAT0->STATUS&~_USART_STATUS_TXC_MASK)|USART_STATUS_TXC) /*Transmition finished*/
}
```

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]